# C# API to create webpage thumbnail

Tags: c#, api, thumbnails

Is there an API that can be used to generate thumbnails of a webpage in C#?  I don't want to use third-party websites as I'd rather render them myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [program on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Website_Thumbnails_in_C.aspx?msg=1964605) that might fit the bill...it's a "console" app (really a hidden WinForms app) using the WebBrowser control.

I played around with it a while back and it works pretty well

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to do it using GTK and Geko(Firefox) engine: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2004/Jun-14.html

You should be able to do the same using Internet Explorer and WindowsForms if you prefer that.

LE: You do need to use an existing rendering engine like(Firefox's Geko, or Webkit, or Internet Explorer) instead of a html parser as this will allow you to capture the page as it is, with CSS, Flash, Java, etc

Comment: Re: Winforms and IE, It's been a long time since I've tried it (so they might've changed things) but it used to be you couldn't render a browser control to a bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

I use WebShot's C# interface and the System.Graphics API to generate thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick-and-dirty approach, you can instantiate an IE browser control and call the [DrawToBitmap](http://thepursuitofalife.com/the-missing-drawtobitmap-function-in-the-net-webbrowser-class/) method. HOWEVER, this method is not strictly intended for public consumption. But it's accessible, and it does work. I wouldn't use it in production though.